# how to display data points from a csv file to a google map uning d3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, csv, d3.js

I am trying to display some data points in a csv file on a Google Map using d3 in my responsive website. The google map is displayed as expected and works fine however the data points are not being displayed can anyone help? :(

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // Create the Google Map…           
        var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5000, 0.1167),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        // Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
        d3.json("stations.json", function(data) {
          var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

          // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
          overlay.onAdd = function() {
            var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
                .attr("class", "stations");

            // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
            // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
            overlay.draw = function() {
              var projection = this.getProjection(),
                  padding = 10;

              var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
                  .data(d3.entries(data))
                  .each(transform) // update existing markers
                .enter().append("svg:svg")
                  .each(transform)
                  .attr("class", "marker");

              // Add a circle.
              marker.append("svg:circle")
                  .attr("r", 4.5)
                  .attr("cx", padding)
                  .attr("cy", padding);

              // Add a label.
              marker.append("svg:text")
                  .attr("x", padding + 7)
                  .attr("y", padding)
                  .attr("dy", ".31em")
                  .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

              function transform(d) {
                d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value[1], d.value[0]);
                d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                return d3.select(this)
                    .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");  
              }
            };
          };

          // Bind our overlay to the map…
          overlay.setMap(map);    

          // Plot data points from .csv file
        d3.csv("data/data.csv", function(csv) {

            d3.selectAll("circle")
                .data(csv)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return projection([d.lat, d.lon])[0];
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return projection([d.lat, d.lon])[1];
                })
                .attr("r", 5)
                .style("fill", "red")
                .style("opacity", 0.90);            
        });
        });

    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

This script has worked for me in the past...

```
// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.6520, -82.3250),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var data = {% raw said %};

// Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
    overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");

    // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
    // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
    overlay.draw = function() {
      var projection = this.getProjection(),
          padding = 30;

    var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
      .data(d3.entries(data))
      .each(transform) // update existing markers
      .enter().append("svg:svg")
      .each(transform)
      .attr("class", "marker");


    //Create color Scale
    var cScale = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain([0, d3.max(d3.entries(data), function(d) { return d.value['Status_count']; })])
                   .range(["orange","yellow"]);         

    //Create radius Scale
    var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                   .domain([0, d3.max(d3.entries(data), function(d) { return d.value['Status_count']; })])
                   .range([5, 15]);         

    // Add a circle.
    marker.append("svg:circle")
      .transition()
      .delay(1000)
      .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale(d.value['Status_count']);})           
      .attr("cx", padding)
      .attr("cy", padding)
      .attr('opacity', 0.75)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {return cScale(d.value['Status_count']);});


    // Add a label.
    marker.append("svg:text")
     .transition()
     .delay(1000)
     .attr("x", padding + 1)
     .attr("y", padding)
     .attr("dy", ".31em")            
     .text(function(d) { return d.value['Status_count']; });

    function transform(d) {
    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value['LAT'], d.value['LON']);
    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
    return d3.select(this)
        .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
        .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
    }


    }; // overlay.draw
    }; // overlay.onAdd

// Bind our overlay to the map…
overlay.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Thank you DataByDavid for this, however the map is now not loading at all with the above answer or I maybe de doing something wrong. The thing is that I need to find a way to plot data point onto my existing map from a csv file I have stored on my PC.

Comment: make sure to replace this line..."var data = {% raw said %};". What server are you using?

Comment: I have altered the line you specified in the answers below however, things seem to be the same. Really would appreciate any assistance you could provide here, many thanks

Comment: the data points I am trying to plot are on my PC and not a server

Comment: send me the code and data files and I will mess with it after the weekend... pichonz@gmail.com